# How can I get rid of a memory leak in my Android app involving a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, callback, broadcastreceiver

Here is the code for my initializer:

```
        public void Initialize(MainActivity activity)
        {
            context = activity;
            store = activity.store;
            gui = activity.gui;
            store.Initialize(activity);
            initialized = true;  // note the this is initialized to TRUE
        }
```

Here is the code for my class constructor:

```
        public TextReceiver()
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("DEBUG", "CREATED a receiver :" + counter.ToString());
            toKill = counter++;
        }
```

Here is the code for my work-around:

```
        public void Refresh()
        {
            initialized = true;
            store = context.store;
            gui = context.gui;
        }
```

Here is the code for my callback:

```
        public override void OnReceive(Context contextPass, Intent intent)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("DEBUG", "receiving a text message: initialized - [" + initialized.ToString() + "]");
            if (initialized == false) { Refresh(); }  // this is my current work-around
                                                      // but I fear this leaks memory
            if (intent.HasExtra("pdus") && (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(context, Manifest.Permission.ReadSms) == Permission.Granted))
            {
                Bundle MessageInfo = intent.Extras;
                Java.Lang.Object[] pdus = (Java.Lang.Object[])MessageInfo.Get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage toSend = null;
                    // Verizon phones use the string "3gpp2"
                    // Some other carriers use the sting
                    // "3gpp". If the version is not correct,
                    // this section will throw an exeception
                    try   { toSend = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])(pdus[i]), "3gpp2"); }
                    catch { toSend = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])(pdus[i]), "3gpp");  }

                    if (store.Push(toSend) == true) // checks for duplicates
                    {
                        gui.TextsReceived();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

The log file is large, but here is the significant section:

```
11-13 14:10:50.984  Google Pixel 3  Error   26765   Bugle   zdt: Jibe SDK Service not available. Is the Jibe SDK service running? Did you call connect() and wait for the notification before calling an API function?
```

Note that the bug report mentions a service which is not running:

```
Is the Jibe SDK service running? 
Did you call connect() and wait for the notification before calling an API function?
```

Is this a result of the way I am using the callback? Am I calling the callback improperly somehow?

My work-around works, but I fear it leaks memory because it instantiates a new BroadcastReciever with each callback and doesn't ever free the instance as far as I can tell.

Some more details:
[image: Debug Flow]

Comment: "As far as I can tell", seems to not have any factual data behind it. Did you try running your App with a profiler attached to back up that claim? I think the question is missing some context for some of the code blocks. It is unclear where you are setting up your BroadcastReceivers. Also the Jibe SDK errors you are getting, where do you see those? Are you using Jibe SDK in your App?

Comment: That's the clue I needed ! Jibe also goes by the name RCS. I see multiple RCS errors on the error log. I don't start any RCS services explicitly. They must be started by the BroadcastReceiver under the hood as it were - Thanks for the clue !